# How do you align text horizontally to a text box?

Tags: html, css

I have tried using `text-align: right`, however it still doesn't work. I am trying to create a comment section for a dummy website for a BTEC ICT project that I am working on.

Here is a code for the comment section:

```css
#respond {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#respond {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="respond">
  <form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
    <label for="comment_author" class="required">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="comment_author" id="comment_author" value="" tabindex="1" required="required">

    <label for="email" class="required">Your email;</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2" required="required">

    <label for="comment" class="required">Your message</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="1" id="comment_post_ID" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit comment" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Oh and by the way, this isn't **my** original code so I might not be able to answer some questions that might be asked.

Comment: What are you trying to align to the right?

Comment: Just text like headers and paragraphs

Comment: In your example code are heading tags nor paragraphs...

Comment: that's because I don't know how to input it into this example

Comment: From your example code what are you trying to align to the right?

Comment: nothing in the code, but how would I be able to align a paragraph on the right?

Comment: Like aligning text next to an image (which I can do) I would also like to learn how to do that with with a textbox such as this

Comment: Try using ```margin``` instead of ```text-align``` in this case.

Comment: Or try using `display: block;`. labels are `display: inline;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fixed it for you.

All you have to do is just put `text-align : right`, or right or left, depending on which side you want to align, inside the

`#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea`

CSS

```css
#respond {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  //text-align:center;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#respond {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="respond">
  <form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
    <label for="comment_author" class="required">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="comment_author" id="comment_author" value="" tabindex="1" required="required">

    <label for="email" class="required">Your email;</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2" required="required">

    <label for="comment" class="required">Your message</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="1" id="comment_post_ID" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit comment" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to align everything on the right?

```css
#respond {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#respond label,
#respond input[type='submit'] {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="respond">
  <form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
    <label for="comment_author" class="required">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="comment_author" id="comment_author" value="" tabindex="1" required="required">

    <label for="email" class="required">Your email;</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2" required="required">

    <label for="comment" class="required">Your message</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="1" id="comment_post_ID" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit comment" />
  </form>
</div>
```

If so, use :

```
  float: right;
  clear: right;
```

Comment: No. I think we are trying to align the labels to the right of the textbox(but still on top).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: block;` and `width: 50%` with `text-align: right;`.

```css
#respond {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#respond {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#respond input[type='text'],
#respond input[type='email'],
#respond textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

#respond label {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="respond">
  <form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
    <label for="comment_author" class="required">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="comment_author" id="comment_author" value="" tabindex="1" required="required">

    <label for="email" class="required">Your email;</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2" required="required">

    <label for="comment" class="required">Your message</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="1" id="comment_post_ID" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit comment" />
  </form>
</div>
```